# Is it possible to change cell value by dictionaly in Pandas DataFrame by iteration over list in the cell

Tags: python, pandas

UPDATED

Pandas DataFram I have a column that contains a list like the below in cells

```
df_lost['Article]

out[6]:

37774    186-2, 185-3, 185-2
37850           358-1, 358-4
37927                       
38266                  111-2
38409                  111-2
38508                       
38519                  185-1
41161           185-4, 357-1
42948                  185-1
Name: Article, dtype: object
```

for each entry like '182-2', '111-2' etch I have a dictionary like

```
aDict = {'111-2': 'Text-1', '358-1': 'Text-2'.....}'
```

is it possible to iterate over the list in the df cells and change the value to the value of a key from the dictionary?

Expected result:

```
 37774    ['Text 1, Text 2, Text -5']
....
```

I have tried to use the map function

```
df['Article'] = df['Article'].map(aDict)
```

but it doesn't work with the list in a cell. As a temp solution, I have created the dictionary

```
aDict = {'186-2, 185-3, 185-2': 'Test - 1, test -2, test -3".....}
```

this works but the number of combinations is extremely big

Comment: The list in the cell only has one element. It's a single string with comma-separated substrings. Why don't you make them separate strings instead of one string? like `['186-2', '185-3', '185-2']`

Comment: Your inputs are ambiguous. Please provide them in the form of a reproducible input. For instance the output of `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's already a built-in type name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string at the comma delimiters, and then look up each element in the dictionary. You also have to index the list to get the string out of the first element, and wrap the result string back into a list.

```
def convert_string(string_list, mapping):
    items = string[0].split(', ')
    new_items = [mapping.get(i, i) for i in items]
    return [', '.join(new_items)]

df['Article'] = df['Article'].map(convert_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) here:

```
aDict = {'111-2': 'Text1', '358-1': 'Text 2'}

import re
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, aDict))

df['Article'] = df['Article'].str.replace(pattern, lambda m: aDict[m.group()], regex=True)
```

*NB. If the dictionary keys can overlap (ab/abc), then they should be sorted by decreasing length to generate the pattern.*

Output:

```
                   Article
37774  186-2, 185-3, 185-2
37850        Text 2, 358-4
37927                     
38266                Text1
38409                Text1
38508                     
38519                185-1
41161         185-4, 357-1
42948                185-1
```